# Get upvote and downvote count

Tags: support, vote-count, keyboard-shortcuts

Stack Overflow some time displays upvote and downvote like this:

[image]

And most of the time displays like this:

[image]

Is there any keystroke to switch view? when Stack Overflow displays both upvote and downvote?

Comment: If you click in the 2nd view you get the 1st one (if +1000 reputation). To switch from 1st to 2nd the only way I find is to reload the page.

Comment: @fedorqui - Another way without reloading: either wait for someone's vote on that post or vote yourself (not recommanded).

Comment: You can also double-click on either the up or down arrow.  This votes and then immediately retracts the vote, but it also resets the display without reloading.

Answer (score 7):

> When Stack Overflow displays both upvote and downvote?

If you have [1000+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) then you can click on the votes count to see exact votes (the individual up and down votes)

[image]

> Is there any keystroke to switch view?

If you have opened the detailed view then to see the sum of votes:

- Reload the page
- Wait for someone to vote on that post
- Vote yourself (**Not recommended** because voting is not for that.)

Comment: Since the OP doesn't have 1k rep, he might be interested in the [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) Chrome extension / user script.

Comment: @RobW - I think he is already using that. Otherwise he can't see that votes.